# Dataframe datetime switching month into days

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I am trying to convert a day/month/Year Hours:Minutes column into just day and month. When I run my code, the conversion switches the months into days and the days into months.

You can find a copy of my dataframe with the one column I want to switch to Day/Month here
https://file.io/JkWl7fsBN0vl

Below is the code I am using to convert:

```
    df =pd.read_csv('Example.csv')
    df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
    df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: The file which you've uploaded doesn't exist. Update your question.

Comment: You'll need to format to string, have a look at `strftime`

Comment: So sorry, looks like the link expired. Below is an updated link: https://filebin.net/wwo092r8cmm973w2

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact DateTime format you are using (the link to the dataframe is broken), I'm going to use an example of

day/month/Year Hours:Minutes

05/09/2014 12:30

You can determine the exact format date code using [this site](https://strftime.org/)

Essentially, to_datetime() has a format argument where you can pass in the specific format when it is not immediately obvious. This will let you specify that what it keeps confusing for month -> day, day -> month is actually the opposite.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['05/09/2014 12:30'],columns=['DateTime'])
      DateTime
0     05/09/2014 12:30

>>> df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
      DateTime
0     2014-09-05 12:30:00


>>> df['day'] = df['DateTime'].dt.day
>>> df['month'] = df['DateTime'].dt.month
      DateTime                day       month
0     2014-09-05 12:30:00     5         9


>>> df['DD/MM'] = df['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%d/%m')
      DateTime                day       month     DD/MM
0     2014-09-05 12:30:00     5         9         05/09
```

I'm unsure about the exact format you want the day and month available in (separate columns, combined), but I provided a few examples, so you can remove the DateTime column when you're done with it and use the one you need.

Comment: I am reading through your comment, thank you. I also updated the link here: https://filebin.net/wwo092r8cmm973w2

Comment: I also changed my code to the following to account for the Seconds and the AM/PM      
     df =pd.read_csv('Example.csv')
    df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'],format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
    df.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)                                                                                  But I get an error when I run the code

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Based on the new link you added, it looks like you have two-digit years, no seconds data, and no AM/PM data, so there is no need to include that. Using format is a signal of what datetime should expect, and that is not actually in there. I recommend trying %d/%m/%y %H:%M as the argument since that is how the data is actually formatted.